# How do I encode the percent symbol in a DTD?

Tags: unicode, urlencode, dtd

How do I encode the percent sign in a DTD?

The following syntax is invalid due to '%' sign

`<!ATTLIST disk unit_of_measurement (TB|TiB|GB|GiB|MB|MiB|kB|KiB|B|s|percent|percentage|%) #REQUIRED>`

I've also tested the & # 37 ; syntax with no better success

What is the trick to tell that the percent sign is a valid value for attribute unit_of_measurement?

Comment: If I convert this DTD to XSD, would there be any change to achieving this?

I mean, can I have an xml document having "%" as a parameter content?

Like <disk unit_of_measurement="%"> partitions description </disk>

(or at last: <disk unit_of_measurement="&#25;"> partitions description </disk>

Comment: You can have `%` in an attribute value, but you'd have to declare the attribute as `CDATA`. When you have an [enumeration](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Enumeration), the values must be valid [Nmtoken](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Nmtoken)'s (whos characters must be valid [NameChar](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameChar)'s).